# Delete trailing white space from all projectile project files

Tags: projectile, whitespace

**Problem**

So the problem is pretty straight forward I'm just trying to get delete trailing spaces from all files in a projectile project.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
(defun projectile-delete-trailing-white-spaces-from-project-files ()
  "Deletes trailing spaces from all projectile project files."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((list (projectile-current-project-files))
         (buffer (car list)))
    (while buffer
      (message buffer)
      (when
        (when (file-exists-p buffer)
          (set-buffer (find-file-noselect buffer))
          (delete-trailing-whitespace) ;; <-- This isn't working?
          (save-buffer))               ;; <-- This isn't working?
        (setq list (cdr list))
        (setq buffer (car list))
        ))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting Jack's answer slightly:

```
(defun projectile-whitespace-cleanup-project-files ()
  "Run `whitespace-cleanup' on all project files."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (file (projectile-current-project-files))
    (let ((path (concat (projectile-project-root) file)
          (buffer (find-file-noselect path)))
      (when buffer
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          (whitespace-cleanup)
          (save-buffer)
          (kill-buffer)))))
```

Comment: @ksrb I did not want to simply reject your proposed edit, but there was no option to add a comment.  :(  Anyway, I don't even have a `projectile-switch-to-project` command, so I wonder if you need to upgrade the package, maybe there's a bug that's causing the behavior you described.  I don't understand why this code would save files in a different directory; as far as I know, `find-file-noselect` should open the file, and `save-buffer` should save the buffer to the file it's backed by.  Either way, I think using `cd` is probably not a good idea; better to work with the file's full path.

Comment: It was saving in the wrong directory for me when I opened a file in a subdirectory using <kbd>C-p p</kbd>.

Comment: Hmm no way to edit comments -_-. Oh and `code`(projectile-switch-to-project)`code` was a typo on my part I meant `code`(projectile-switch-project)`.

Comment: @ksrb Okay, I tracked down the problem to `projectile-current-project-files` returning filenames relative to the current directory.  I edited this answer to add the project root directory, which fixes the problem.  Also it kills buffers now, so it doesn't leave open ones behind.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
(defun projectile-delete-trailing-white-spaces-from-project-files ()
  "Deletes trailing spaces from all projectile project files."
  (interactive)
  (let ((project-files (projectile-current-project-files)))
    (dolist (pr project-files)
      (when (file-exists-p pr)
        (message "clearing trailing whitespace in %s" pr)
        (with-temp-buffer
          (insert-file-contents pr)
          (delete-trailing-whitespace (point-min) (point-max))
          (write-file pr))))))
```

Although not certain it's the best way to do it.